# RecyclerView still displays images after removing them

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm facing some problems with removing positions (mainly images) from RecyclerView. I store images in app's memory and have a reference in DB to them (as a path).

Additionally, I use glide to load images from memory into images View. I tried to implement deleting a pics:

- I removed a database rows (using ContentREsolver & ContentProvider)
- I removed the image from the memory and the list containing pics

Information (list of MyFunnyImg objects)
Everything looks fine at first - the image disappears from list but after reentering this fragment (containing recyclerView) the image suddenly appears...

I tried to find something in the Internet but nothing worked, here is my code ( in 'developing' state):

deleting method from ContentProvider:

```
@Override
public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String where, @Nullable String[] whereArgs) {
    int numbersOfRowsDeleted=0;
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case ONE_PIC:
            numbersOfRowsDeleted=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().delete(DatabaseDescription.Picture.TABLE_NAME_,
                   DatabaseDescription.Picture._ID+"="+uri.getLastPathSegment(),whereArgs);

            break;
        default:
            unsupportedOperation();
    }
    if(numbersOfRowsDeleted>0){
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
    }
    return numbersOfRowsDeleted;
}
```

methods from RecyclerViewAdapter for deleting images and rows from DB

```
private boolean onSingleMenuItemClick(MenuItem item,ImageView imageView,int position){
    int id=item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.share:
           // instructions
            break;
        case R.id.more_info:
           // instructions
            break;
        case R.id.delete_img:
            deleteImg(position);
            break;
        default:
            //instructions
    }
    return true;
}



private void deleteImg(int position){
    removeImgFile(argsToShow.get(position).getFileName());
    deleteFromDatabase(position);
    argsToShow.remove(position);
    //notifyDataSetChanged();
   // notifyItemRemoved(position);

    notifyItemRangeChanged(position,argsToShow.size());
}`private void removeImgFile(String fName){



    String root=null;
    try {
        root = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    }catch(NullPointerException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error","NullPointerException while deleting BitMap");
    }




    File dir=new File(root+"/saved_images");

    File file=new File(dir,fName);

}

private void deleteFromDatabase(int position){

    // we create URI referrimng to whole table
    Uri uri= DatabaseDescription.Picture.CONTENT_URI;

    String id=String.valueOf(position);

    uri=uri.buildUpon().appendPath(id).build();

    ContentResolver contentResolver=activity.getContentResolver();

   int count= contentResolver.delete(uri,null,null);
   ViewUtils.showToast(activity,"Deleted: "+count+" rows");
}
```

Comment: "it is definitely messy but I hope someone will try to figure it out"

How rude! Instead, please provide a minimal code example that shows the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry didn't get your comment at first. ;) I changed Code to be more informative.  :)

Comment: Well done. Fingers crossed on the answers!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion!